# .NET reactor : date expiration lock and system date tampering

Tags: .net, licensing, net-reactor

With .NET reactor API, I've generated an 'Expirated at Date" license (for instance, software is protected and under license until 16th Feb 2016).

What if, on the host machine (WinServer 2008), the system date is tampered with because someone tries to extend the license indefinitely ?

Comment: Why are you asking a what will happens question that take 10 seconds to try? If you did try something can you make it more obvious because I'm sure most peoples who see your question wonder why you didn't try doing it.

Comment: Because it's a theorical question; I haven't yet code my license generator API neither license validation API (waiting my corp to order it...) . And I've to foresee what actions I might take to counter such tampering from a developper point of view. I thought it was best to ask to those who had experience dealing with software licensing and their best practices.(of course, I've asked Eziriz support and I'm still waiting for their answers too)

Answer (score 0):

Once the trial or license is expired it remains expired even if you manipulate the system date.